# Choosing the appropriate statistical test

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, biostatistics, controlling-for-a-variable

I am trying to examine the long-term association between smoking cannabis and a diagnosis of depression. I have survey data from 2 points in time for the same participant (repeated measures).
The variable in my dataset are cnb_smoke (1: yes, 0: no), diag_depr (1: yes, 0: no), occasion (1: occasion 1, 2: occasion 2), and ppt_id (unique ID).
I am also interested in including the following confounders: sex (1:female,0:male) and age (continuous)

What statistical tests, other than multilevel models, can I use to test the long term association; i.e. what model would allow me to account for the repeated measures nature of the design?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Why do you not prefer multilevel (or mixed) models?

Comment: @T.E.G. I'm avoiding using mixed models as I am not too familiar with them in the context of longitudinal data, so just wondering if there's any other way to approach this.

Comment: Almost same Q by same poster:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505378/exploring-long-term-associations-in-stata